# I baked breads, rolls, pizzas, marinated meats starting with a cold oven to use less energy. Is my “strategy” unpromising when baking sweet desserts?

Tags: baking, heat, baking-soda, baking-powder, blind-baking

My strategy is as in the topic, plus near the end, I switch the oven off and then use the still accumulated heat to cook food. I think I have a good intuition as far as baking savoury items is concerned.

I make notes on how long it took to cook and I write it down so that I can replicate my results in the future (at least with the same oven) without constant checking (to save my time, and to save on heat loss when opening the oven door) - which works, my results are replicable. I make sure not to cut into baked food for some time (also written down), as even after taking it out of the oven the cooking on the inside still continues.

Now I'm not sure how my intuition would apply to sweet baked desserts, because I'm not knowledgable when it comes to the chemistry of baking. I know how yeast behave (in practical terms), but don't know how baking powders and baking sodas do - for e.g. would my brownies collapse because due to initially low-temperature steam trapping crust didn't form on top? Etc...